# Ubuntu boots in 2D mode on GT 540M

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, nvidia-optimus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. In live mode, ubuntu booted in "3d" mode. But after installing it would always login in 2d mode. I have nvidia graphics card geforce gt 540m. Should I install any extra packages? What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed any drivers?

Run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`in terminal.

Then press ctrl-alt-f1 in desktop and run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
sudo reboot
```

Comment: nvidia-current is already installed. when I have run nvidia-xconfig, an error message has come up 
Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".

VALIDATION ERROR: Data incomplete in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.
                  Device section "Default Device" must have a Driver line.

Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'

Comment: what is the output when you type sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings ?

Comment: I ran nvidia-xconfig after killing lightdm. But now the screen is in a poorer resolution, and open the nvidia-settings window still prompts "run nvidia-xconfig as root"

Comment: the output is that the packages are already installed